# Grid in Container is not displayed in a row but as a column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I code exactly like in a current YouTube video, in the video the cards are shown in a row, in my case they are strangely as a column.

Why? Default should actually be in line. Even if I explicitly enter direction="row" in the grid container, it still doesn't help.

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import TourCard from "./components/TourCards";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <Grid Container spacing={4} direction="row">
          <TourCard />
          <TourCard />
          <TourCard />
          <TourCard />
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TourCards.js

```
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { Grid, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Logo from "../logo.svg";

const TourCard = () => {
  return (
    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <Paper elevation={3}>
        <img
          src={Logo}
          alt="logo"
          clasName="img"
        />
        <Typography>Nr.1</Typography>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default TourCard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the capital `C` in `<Grid Container spacing={4} direction="row">` -- it should be a lower case `c` for example:

```
<Grid container spacing={4}>
  <TourCard />
  <TourCard />
  <TourCard />
  <TourCard />
</Grid>
```

It is the `container` prop that causes `display: flex` to be applied to the `Grid` container.  Using improper case on a prop is the same as omitting it, as the props are case-sensitive.

[image]

Simplified reproduction of the error and correction: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicgrid-material-demo-forked-un6nk?file=/demo.js

Comment: Great thanks! Sometimes mistakes are due to small things, but you think about something global. :)